# Should I do the multiple comparisons after the 2 between-group paired t-test?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, paired-data, false-discovery-rate

I have some problems with my statistics. I need to help.

I have about 8 different variables on 14 subjects.
Each variable contains 5 regional and 1 total value.
Thus, the total number of variables is 48.
Each subject has two phases before and after treatment.
Therefore, I performed a paired test for all variables.

My statistical analysis was in two steps.
First, I performed log-transform for all variables.
Next, I conducted a paired t-test for all comparisons. (alpha = 0.05)
The significance variable was only 5 variables.

My question is as follows.

1. Should I do multiple comparisons such as FDR after t-test?!
   If I have to do FDR, why should I do this work? I think each variable is independent, so a single analysis (paired t-test) is ok. I do not know why the reviewer commented on the 1 type error correction.
2. How can I control the high FDR (high q value)?
3. Further, if the q value is high (over than 50%), cannot report the result of comparisons although 5 variables were significant?

I look forward to your reply.

Thank you.

Joon Woo

Answer (score 2):

1. You should do some type of adjustment for multiple testing. Otherwise, you could expect to find 2 or 3 significant tests out of 48 even when there was no difference before and after for all 48 variables. Here is a funny example that shows why adjustment is needed [IgNobel Prize in Neuroscience: The dead salmon study](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/scicurious-brain/ignobel-prize-in-neuroscience-the-dead-salmon-study/)
2. The simplest way is to use the [Benjamini-Hochberg procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate#Benjamini%E2%80%93Hochberg_procedure)
3. I would report both the adjusted and unadjusted p-values. If none of the adjusted p-values are significant, then it seems like there is no effect of the treatment or the effect is too small to be detected with the sample size used in your study, or there were other problems with the study.  I would still report the results of all the comparisons and state what was learned.  Maybe all that was learned is there is no effect of the treatment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My data set is a paired one by one and each variable is not dependent. Although this, have I also to do the multiple comparisons? And I already performed the Benjamini-Hochberg adjustment. However, the smallest q value was 0.4909. Based on your comment, though this implies the treatment effect was too small or not significant, I can report this value in my manuscript and discuss it. My understanding is right?